# wordpress theme Not Acceptable An appropriate representation of the requested resource /wp-admin/customize.php could not be found on this server

Tags: wordpress, themes

live preview of my wordpress theme causes this error !

"Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /wp-admin/customize.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

any help ?!

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code generating the error?

Comment: no !! i just upload the theme and tried to preview it